# Syncing iPod touch

Tags: ipod

I would like to *sync* my iPod Touch 4G (64GB) in Ubuntu. As far as I know, it is impossible to *sync* it (ie: I can simply copy music on it).

If I Jailbreak the iPod, will I be able to sync all my music library with it? If yes, how? Is anyone aware of how to sync it without jailbreaking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this, using 16.04.
You are correct. Though it is possible to connect to your iPod Touch in Ubuntu, you will be unable to sync music via any of the normal libgpod based strategies, listed in other answers.

It is possible to use VBox as detailed above, and you can even get Wifi sync to work between itunes and the ipod. I never found this reliable.

I jailbroke my iPod touch (ios 6.1.6) and then installed (and paid for) [PwnTunes](http://www.pwntunes.net/) on the iPod. This sets up a new 'My Music' folder on the ipod. When you add music to this folder, [PwnTunes](http://www.pwntunes.net/) will sync it to the ipod Music library, including metadata and cover art (which can be embedded or in the form of a cover.jpg file in each folder).
It's a good solution, and works even better across ssh!

Answer (score 0):

For syncing iPod you can use various software, including the following:

- [Banshee](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/banshee/)
- [Rhythmbox](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/rhythmbox/), installed by default in Ubuntu
- [Amarok](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/amarok/), installed by default in Kubuntu
- [GtkPod](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gtkpod/), a program only for this purpose (you can get newer version on official site)

More here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPod

Or you can run iTunes via Wine, but it is known to only work bad, if at all:

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=1347

Also you should install the `libgpod` library, but it is mostly installed as dependency of the programs above.

**EDIT:**

Or try: http://www.libimobiledevice.org/, it uses `libgpod` for syncing, so I don't know if it will work, but you can give it a chance.

Comment: Banshee and Amarok do not allow me to sync my music library with the iPod. They just let me copy song by song on the iPod. Rhythmbox doesn't recognize my iPod. iTunes via wine is reported not to support any device (from wine website reports).

Comment: @user3161330 use gtkpod instead, the program I added to the answer.

Comment: @the_Seppi seriously? Proper formatting is one thing, but this makes me little angry :) I was going to add this information, but I couldn't because you already made the changes :D, and it won't let me ...it is no big deal, I'm not that narrow-minded...

Comment: @the_Seppi GtkPod doesn't allow syncronization. I can simply copy song by song. Am I wrong maybe? I did try it and that's what i found out.

Comment: I can undo it if you want to...

Comment: No, of course not ;)

Comment: What are the perks of jailbreaking the ipod in terms of syncing?

Comment: @user3161330 you can [move whole playlists](http://www.gtkpod.org/wiki/IPod_and_content#Copying_content_to_the_iPod) using gtkpod.

Answer (score 0):

The only 100% functional answer I have found to this problem is to install Windows 7 in a virtual machine.  I dislike being chained to Win7 this way but I also want to keep my iPod Touch functional.

Edit: here is how I set it up using VirtualBox.

- Install Win 7 in VirtualBox
- In System Settings/Details/removable media, set Music Player and Photos to Do Nothing
- In Ubuntu Tweak / Tweaks/File Manager set to not open window on USB insertion
- Start Win 7, download and install iTunes
- Start iTunes
- Plug in iPod
- Unlock iPod when it starts (if screen lock enabled).
- Close Linux windows/error messages relating to iPod and any apps that start.
- In Vbox Devices/USB Devices menu, click on Ipod,
- Allow Windows to install iPod drivers.
- wait till iPod appears in iTunes
- Should be able to use iTunes as normal with iPod now.

Comment: Does it work with virtualbox or do you use kvm?

Comment: I use virtualbox.

Comment: You can also set up wifi sync this way, but you have to set your Network Interface to 'bridge' mode in VBox.