# iPod touch not syncing - ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sync, rhythmbox, ipod

After upgrading to ubuntu 16.04 I can no longer sync my iPod touch (MC008FD, 3rd generation, 32 GB - yes, I know it's an old model, but I really like that one) with *Rhythmbox*. The device is simply ignored and does not show up in the panel on the left.

Attempts to use *amarok* and *gtkpod* instead of *Rhythmbox* were unsuccessful. While *amarok* apologizes ("Sorry - Connecting to iPhone, iPad or iPod touch failed"), *gtkpod* simply pretends that there is no device. However, the iPod is recognized by the system when I plug it into the USB port: it is displayed in the launcher along with its documents. Alas, the music remains inaccessible.

A couple of the relevant libraries are already installed:

```
~$ dpkg -l libgpod4 libimobiledevice6  libplist3 usbmuxd libusbmuxd4
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                      Version           Architecture      Description
+++-=========================-=================-=================-========================================================
ii  libgpod4:amd64            0.8.3-6ubuntu2    amd64             library to read and write songs and artwork to an iPod
ii  libimobiledevice6:amd64   1.2.0+dfsg-3~ubun amd64             Library for communicating with the iPhone and iPod Touch
ii  libplist3:amd64           1.12-3.1          amd64             Library for handling Apple binary and XML property lists
ii  libusbmuxd4:amd64         1.0.10-2ubuntu0.1 amd64             USB multiplexor daemon for iPhone and iPod Touch devices
ii  usbmuxd                   1.1.0-2           amd64             USB multiplexor daemon for iPhone and iPod Touch devices
```

I understand that a number of similar questions have been asked before, and I made sure to read the pertinent posts, like "[How to sync songs in Rhythmbox with an iPod](https://askubuntu.com/q/90027/493814)" and "[Syncing iPod touch](https://askubuntu.com/q/637046/493814)", as well as various documentations provided, e.g., [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone#Syncing_with_Rhythmbox) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPod) before asking this question. Possibly I have overlooked something, but I have tried for some time and could not find any answer or hint that would solve the problem.

What surprises me is that *Rhythmbox* used to sync with that same iPod seamlessly with ubuntu 15.10. The appearance of the problem seems to have coincided with the OS upgrade. I am therefore reluctant to resign myself to concluding the that "it just doesn't work".

I would be very grateful for suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is now solved to a sufficient degree in the sense that the iPod is recognized by amarok and by gtkpod. (Rhythmbox still does not see that iPod on ubuntu 16.04).

Because I have tried many things to resolve the problem, I am not sure what exactly made the difference. But I believe that the following commands were important:

```
sudo apt-get install fuse libimobiledevice-utils ideviceinstaller
idevicepair pair    
chmod 777 /media/iPod
ifuse /media/iPhone/
```

Further, I edited the file `/etc/fuse.conf` and uncommented the line `user_allow_other` therein. Essentially I followed the steps described in detail [here](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/linux-iphone-6.html).

I post this as an answer to my own question, hoping that it will be helpful for others. In any case, as far as I'm concerned, the problem is solved.