# iTunes to synchronize ipod shuffle

Tags: wine, sync, music, ipod

I am a beginner of ubuntu 18.04 and I would like to synchronize music from my pc to my iPod shuffle

Is there an alternative to iTunes via wine to transfer music-files pc to the ipod?

I tested the itunes via wine but it doesn't work. After the start of itunes (I have tested the 32bit-version and the 64bit version of itunes) the screen has been black so that  I can't recognize the labels, menus, etc.
And I find it very complex.

Is there an alternative to itunes? I would not like to use itunes as a music player - i would like to use it only for transfer the music via drag&drop to ipod.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syncing iPod touch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637046/syncing-ipod-touch)

Comment: thanks. this article was fine. Now I have tested gtkpod, and it works very good and it was very easy to install. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Clementine works perfectly for me. Rhythmbox screwed up my playlists, duplicating existing items in them multiple times.